# How to set a message from working thread to UI in VC++ .NET Windows Form application

Tags: .net, multithreading, visual-c++, c++-cli, tcp

I want to set a message from the working thread to the text box which is in the Form1 UI. The thread is invoked by Form1.h UI.
The project is doing for TCP IP server client communication. I am using visual studio 2008 and frame work is .NET 3.5 for Windows Form application.

Form1 UI Button click event code

```
String^ ipAddrNo=ipAddrText->Text;  
System::Int32 portNumber;
portNumber = System::Convert::ToInt32(portText->Text);
portNumber = System::Int32::Parse(portText->Text); 
serverThread^ objserverThread = gcnew serverThread();
objserverThread->chk=portNumber;
objserverThread->str=ipAddrNo;
Thread^ oThread = gcnew Thread( gcnew ThreadStart(objserverThread,&serverThread::serverListen) );
oThread->Start();
```

Thread code

```
void serverThread::serverListen()
{
    try
    {
         IPAddress^ localAddr = IPAddress::Parse( str );
         TcpListener^ server = gcnew TcpListener( localAddr,port );

         // Start listening for client requests.
         server->Start();
         TcpClient^ client = server->AcceptTcpClient();

         // Buffer for reading data
         array<Byte>^bytes = gcnew array<Byte>(256);
         String^ data = nullptr;
         ASCIIEncoding^ ascii = gcnew ASCIIEncoding; 

         while ( true )
         {
             TcpClient^ client = server->AcceptTcpClient();
             data = nullptr;

              NetworkStream^ stream = client->GetStream();
              Int32 i;

              array<Byte>^ myReadBuffer = gcnew array<Byte>(1024);
              String^ myCompleteMessage = "";
              int numberOfBytesRead = 0;
              do
              {
                 numberOfBytesRead = stream->Read( myReadBuffer, 0,
                 myReadBuffer->Length );
                 myCompleteMessage = String::Concat( myCompleteMessage,
                 ascii->GetString( myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead ));
              }
              while ( stream->DataAvailable );

             // Print out the received message to the console.
             Debug::WriteLine( "You received the following message : {0}",myCompleteMessage );

            // To Do code to set the received message to the text box in form1
            client->Close();
        }
   }
   catch ( SocketException^ e ) 
   {
       Console::WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e );
   }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58cwt3zh.aspx) to communicate the message from your worker thread to your form.

Here is an example.

This is the worker thread class. It exposes a `MessageReady` event that gets called by the thread procedure (`serverListen`) whenever the complete message is available.

```
#include <msclr\lock.h>
using namespace System::Threading;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace msclr;

public delegate void MessageReadyDelegate(String^);

public ref class serverThread
{
public:
    event MessageReadyDelegate^ MessageReady
    {
        void add(MessageReadyDelegate^ handler) {
            lock lockEvent(this);
            _messageReady += handler;
        }
        void remove(MessageReadyDelegate^ handler) {
            lock lockEvent(this);
            _messageReady -= handler;
        }
    protected:
        void raise(String^ message) {
            MessageReadyDelegate^ messageReady = _messageReady;
            if (messageReady)
                messageReady(message);
        }
    }

    void serverListen()
    {
        String^ myCompleteMessage = "";
        /* Do work */
        myCompleteMessage = "abc";

        // Notify that the message is ready.
        MessageReady(myCompleteMessage);
    }

private:
    MessageReadyDelegate^ _messageReady;
};
```

The form class (`Form1`) registers to the event and starts the worker thread. When the event is received, the form class must make a transition on the GUI thread using [Control.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
void Form1::button_Click(System::Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e)
{
    serverThread^ st = gcnew serverThread();
    st->MessageReady += gcnew MessageReadyDelegate(this, &Form1::OnMessageReady);
    Thread^ thread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(st, &serverThread::serverListen));
    thread->Start();
}

void Form1::OnMessageReady(String^ message)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        MessageReadyDelegate^ onMessageReady = gcnew MessageReadyDelegate(this, &Form1::OnMessageReady);
        Invoke(onMessageReady, message);
    }
    else
    {
        textBox->Text = message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a lot of ways to do this.

-Using static class

-Using property in Form. Send address as parameter to Thread.

-Use Event

-File based communication

What do you prefer?
What is you environment, limitations, requirements,... Say more about you program.

UPDATE

I prefer not to write code. It is something you need to do yourself. Here is how to do this

-in Form class make *Property* type you need.

-modify void serverThread::serverListen() to void serverThread::serverListen(Form^)

-modify ThreadStart to  accept "this" pointer

-from serverListen change *Property* as you want

-in Form make timer and check if *Property* changed and display message

Ask if you need more details

Comment: I prefer property in Form. Send address as parameter to Thread.Secondly File based communication.. Or simply give an alternative for sendmessage() in MFC.

Comment: @Michail This is not a good solution. It creates a tight coupling between the worker thread class and the form class. It makes it difficult to unit-test and reuse the worker thread class. It is error-prone because the worker thread might call a form's member that access a GUI element.

Comment: Maybe it is not perfect one. Yes, you need to care about a lot of things. But you are exaggerating. It is not SO bad. I also prefer something else. BUT "customer is always right". He was requested this one. :)